# Find Missing Numbers

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, bash, filesystems, awk

I have a big list of files with names (videos)

I managed to write all file names in a text file. Now I have a text file with a lot of file names (one episode per line)
Now I need something that can read that text file and tell me what episode `E` number is missing

```
S1-E18-(Date)-(Title)-(Random numbers).mp4
```

Here is an example of a list

```
S1-E1-20100526-title-of-video-1400316375.mp4
S1-E3-20100517-title-of-video-15457547.mp4
S10-E5-20100421-title-of-video-14467457.mp4
S5-E7-20120912-title-of-video-17467457.mp4
```

In this case its easy to see that the files `S1-E2` and `S10-E4` are missing. but if I have a big list then how can I find the missing files. (Leave Season number `S1, S2`) just need to check `E` means episode number

The largest existing file's number is `S50-E2184` and The Smallest existing file's number is `S1-E1`

Comment: Your example is not very good.

Comment: Is the number of episodes for each season fixed? or at least known?

Comment: @EricF I tried Nothing

Comment: @harrymc I know my english is not good,

Comment: @glennjackman Numbers are fixed.

Comment: Your English is good enough. I understand that S10-E4 is missing, but what about S10-E1 to E3 and E5 to whatever and we not know the last number. You do not give enough information to understand the full problem.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Sort it with `sort -V` to sort by season then episode, or `sort -t- -k2` to sort only by episode. Then you can run a loop or other to get the missing seasons/episodes.

Answer (score 0):

Save all the names in a file with name "file_with_list_of_files" and run below command in a linux/unix terminal[I tried it in mac terminal]:

```
cat file_with_list_of_files | sed 's/^[A-Z][0-9]*-//g' | grep -v "^E"
```

-- or --

```
cat file_with_list_of_files | awk -F- '{print $2}' | grep -v "^E"
```

This lists all file name does not have a E after first - (hyphen). You may find other better ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a file with all episode signatures. You didn't tell us how many episodes there are in each season but you obviously need to know. This is how you prepare the file:

   ```
   >all_episodes   # just to empty the file which may or may not exist
   printf 'S1-E%s\n'  {1..3}    >>all_episodes   # 3 episodes in season 1
   printf 'S2-E%s\n'  {1..5}    >>all_episodes   # 5 episodes in season 2
   printf 'S3-E%s\n'  {1..8}    >>all_episodes
   # and so on
   printf 'S50-E%s\n' {1..2184} >>all_episodes
   ```

   This assumes each season starts with its own episode number one (your question is not clear about it). The file consist of lines in a form `S<n>-E<m>`, e.g `S2-E3`.
2. Create a file of owned episodes in the same form:

   ```
   cut -d - -f -2 your_current_list >owned_episodes
   ```

   The command takes `-` as a **d**elimiter and returns line fragments up to the **f**ield number 2 from your current list.
3. Treat `owned_episodes` as patterns and filter `all_episodes` to find lines without any pattern:

   ```
   grep -vxFf owned_episodes all_episodes
   ```

   Note we use `-x` here; the point is `S50-E3` shouldn't match `S50-E31`. `-F` is not necessary in your case but *in general* one should use it while supplying fixed strings. The [options](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) are:

   > `-F`
   >   Match using fixed strings. Treat each pattern specified as a string instead of a regular expression. [...]
   >
   > `-f  pattern_file`
   >   Read one or more patterns from the file named by the pathname `pattern_file`. [...]
   >
   > `-v`
   >   Select lines not matching any of the specified patterns. [...]
   >
   > `-x`
   >   Consider only input lines that use all characters in the line excluding the terminating `<newline>` to match an entire fixed string or regular expression to be matching lines.